# Converting Java DSL to Spring XML equivalent

Tags: spring, apache-camel

So this may be a more general question, but I feel it needs to be asked.

Time and time again I come across examples on Camel's documentation pages where I say "that's exactly what I want!... but it's in Java not Spring.  How the heck do I convert it properly?"

So my question is: **What is the rule of thumb for converting things?**

Is there some conversion guide out there?

For example, I wanted to append a `\n` to the end of each line as the data comes through a socket into a file using the Netty4 component.

I see an example such as `.transform().body(append("\n"))`

How would I interpret that as Spring, to put in my Spring-based route?

Maybe this is just a thing that a person new to Camel struggles with and once you get the hang of it you can see the obvious answer.  But I feel like I can't be the only one who's thinking this about the examples out there.

It seems like a lot of Java -> Spring conversion can be done in a 1 to 1 ratio, but that's not all the time.

Comment: Spring is java... You don't need xml you can just use java based configuration.

Comment: The thing is the other developers want to use a Spring XML based configuration.  So I have to walk through the Camel documentation hoping I find an XML equivalent to a Java example because I simply don't know all the potential tags I can use off the top of my head.

Answer (score 1):

Well, the mapping isn't straightforward and there isn't a 1-to-1 mapping available - generally, a Java DSL method invocation will in most cases translate to a tag in Spring XML DSL but the position of that tag is not always the same - in some cases Java DSL method invocation chains translate to tags being placed on the same level, sometimes (e.g. idempotent consumer) the chain translates to child tags of the first invocation.

I guess that the mapping was done this way because XML and Java are two very different languages and making the mapping 1-1 would have crippled the expressiveness of at least one, if not both, DSLs.

My advice would be to always import the [XML schema](https://camel.apache.org/xml-reference.html) and rely on your IDE's auto-completion and the documentations from the schema itself and Camel's online documentation.

Comment: Thanks! This is the type of answer I was looking for. I was just struggling with things like `.transform().body(append("\n"))` and found out that `<transform><simple>${in.body}\n</simple></transform>` would get the same results.  It's just hard to find things in the Camel documentation that would point me to that type of answer (easily anyways)! However, now word came from the boss that we should covert everything from Spring into Java :bangs head on wall:

Comment: Yeah, unfortunately the translation between the two is really not that intuitive. If it's any comfort, I think you're better off with Java DSL, especially if you're using Java 8 - it's much more powerful and flexible. Plus easier to test :)

Answer (score 0):

You can run your camel context via mvn camel:run goal and then use a JMX client to connect to that process. There is an mbean in camel which provides a method called dumpRoutesAsXML or similar. Invoking that one will give u the xml equivalent of your context. But keep in mind that it only prints the routes and all stuff out of routes is discarded.

Hope that helps,
Lars

Comment: Sorry I'm talking about examples I see online or in Camel documentation.  I don't mean that I have this code all set up in Java and want to convert it.  I'm just looking at the plain ol' text on the Camel website and going "how can I convert this to my needs?"